# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '' error in WCF service

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, wcf

### Issue

---

I want my SQL database table primary key ID to increment by 1 automatically when i add a row to the table.

I am using a WCF service and in the DAL (*Data Access Layer*) I am trying to add a row into the database but it keeps passing '0' in as the primary key ID.

### Code

---

This is my DAL, as you can see I am setting all the values. **NOTE** HOLIDAY_ID is the incremented id for the SQL table and i am not passing it any value:

```
public void AddHoliday(string STARTDATE, string ENDDATE)
{

    HOLIDAY_EVENT _newHolidayEvent = new HOLIDAY_EVENT
    {
        USER_ID = 1,
        HOLIDAY_TITLE = "Test1",
        HOLIDAY_START = Convert.ToDateTime(STARTDATE),
        HOLIDAY_END = Convert.ToDateTime(ENDDATE),
        HOLIDAY_EVENT_STATE_ID = 2
    };

    _ENTITY.HOLIDAY_EVENT.Add(_newHolidayEvent);
    _ENTITY.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is the design of my SQL table:

[image]

Here is the way i set the increment of the HOLIDAY_ID:

[image]

### Conclusion

---

In my DAL what do I need to pass to HOLIDAY_ID for the ID to increment automatically?

Comment: SQL already has a solution for this... you can use AUTO INCREMENT..[try this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)..

Comment: @AkshayGupta I have already set my column to AUTO INCREMENT

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` in your model ?

for example:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int HOLIDAY_ID { get; set; }
```

`HOLIDAY_ID` should be available after `SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: What is the namespace for 'Key' and 'DatabaseGenerated'

Comment: System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for Key and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema for DatabaseGenerated